# Given $\int f(x)/x\,dx$, seeking $\int f(x)/(A+Bx)\,dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

Given the value of $\int f(x)/x\,dx$, is there a method to determine the value of $\int f(x)/(A+Bx)\,dx$?

In particular, I'm dealing with $f(x)=J_0(Cx)J_1(Dx)$ and integrating from 0 to $\infty$. $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ are constants.

In case it matters: I have constraints on $C$ and $D$ that allow me to use [a definite integral](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselJ/21/02/02/0001/) I stumbled over at Wolfram Functions, so that's where I'm getting the value of $\int f(x)/x\,dx$ from.

Comment: Are you looking to express the integral as a function of $A$, $B$, and $\int f(x)/x \, dx$?

Comment: In general this doesn't seem particularly simple.  Consider $f(x) = xe^{-x}$.  The indefinite integral $\int f(x)/x\, dx$ is very straightforward, but for any non-zero $A,B$ the indefinite integral $\int xe^{-x}/(A+Bx)\, dx$ can only be expressed in terms of $\text{Ei}(x)$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That'd be simplest, but I'm not holding out much hope of seeing something like that. Like Erick mentions, and as the past year of my own attempts & inquiries have led me to believe, a solution seems really hard. I hope that by asking about a method rather than an expression, and also by generalizing from the specific $f(x)$ shown, I might pick up some insights from others.

Comment: Here is a simple example to consider: let the domain of integration be $(0,\infty)$, let $t > 0$, and let $f(x) = 1$ if $t < x < 2t$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Then $$\int \frac{f(x)}{x} \, dx = \ln 2,\quad \int \frac{f(x)}{x+1} \, dx = \ln \left( \frac{2t+1}{t+2} \right)$$ so that even with $A = B = 1$ the second integral can't depend only on the first.